# Using $(this).val() returns Invalid Postback error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET C# web form that uses jquery to validate user input before that input is handled by the server. When I say "validate", I mean that I check to ensure my user has given input in certain required fields before anything else happens. This check is wired to the "OnClientClick" event of an ASP.NET button control. If the client script finds missing input, it returns false. Otherwise, the button's OnClick event fires.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitBtn" 
   OnClientClick="if (!addBtnClick(event)) { return false; }" 
   UseSubmitBehavior="false"                  
   runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitBtn_Click" />
```

The inputs to be checked consist of textboxes and drop down lists, both of which are coded in the page as server controls, and marked as required by a class value. I check the value of these inputs one at a time using the "each" function, and get the value of the input being checked with "$(this).val()".

```
$(cls).each(function () {
   var val = $(this).val();
   // do other stuff
});
```

My problem is that this is somehow causing an "Invalid postback or callback argument" error, and I know it's "$(this).val()" that's the culprit because if I comment out only that, passing in some generic value to my variable for example, my application runs fine.

I've tried registering my jquery code with RegisterClientScript, but that doesn't change anything. Has anyone seen this before?

EDIT: "$(this).val()" continues to throw this error even if the server-side isn't involved. I'm using this code to reset my form as well, clearing all input fields. After posting this it occurred to me that some of my textboxes have event listeners attached, so maybe this is where the error is coming from?

Turns out, no. Even with my event listeners commented out, I still get the error on the client side. I can use "$('input').val('')" with no problem, but this clears all the input fields and I need to be able to ignore certain ones.

Comment: What is the value of `cls`?

Comment: "cls" is the variable into which I load the class value that marks all the fields that need to be validated. For the record, that value is ".req". 
I'm using a variable because the class identifying required fields changes under given circumstances.